# Reading variable length data over Windows Named Pipes

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I'm coding in C++ and I'm trying to read variable length data on the Server side. The pipes supposed to be full-duplex for sending requests and receiving responses(One pipe for Read and Write).
So I send `[length][data]` over the pipe and trying to first read the length, allocate memory and then read either the rest of the data(I tried `SetFilePointer()` no luck) or in the following code I'm trying to read everything once I know how much memory to allocate.

```
        HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipeA(pipename,
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            0,
            NULL);
        if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            cout << "  CreateNamedPipeA INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        cout << "  NamedPipe created" << endl;

        cout << "  Waiting for incoming connection over pipe..." << endl;
        BOOL bConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);
        if (bConnected != TRUE)
        {
            cout << "  ConnectNamedPipe " << GetLastError() << endl;
            system("pause");
        }

        DWORD dwMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;
        SetNamedPipeHandleState(hPipe, &dwMode, NULL, NULL);

        DWORD dwNumReadL;
        char lenbuf[4];
        memset(lenbuf, 0, sizeof(lenbuf));
        ReadFile(hPipe,
            lenbuf,
            sizeof(DWORD),
            &dwNumReadL,
            NULL);
        DWORD IncomingBufferLength;
        memcpy(&IncomingBufferLength, lenbuf, sizeof(DWORD));
        printf("Incoming Length : %d\n", IncomingBufferLength);


        DWORD dwIncmRead;
        char* IncomingBuffer = (char*)malloc(IncomingBufferLength + sizeof(DWORD));
        memset(IncomingBuffer, 0, IncomingBufferLength);
        ReadFile(hPipe,
            IncomingBuffer,
            IncomingBufferLength,
            &dwIncmRead,
            NULL);
        cout << dwIncmRead << endl;
```

My first `ReadFile()` call is working fine and I can read the length of the data. But the second `ReadFile()` reads 0 from the pipe! I'm running out of ideas and I really appreciate any help.

This is the code that I have on the pipe client side,

```
        char* msg = (char*)malloc(1024);
        if (msg == NULL)
        {
            cout << "ERR : allocation failed" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        DWORD len = strlen(argv[1]);
        memcpy(msg, &len, sizeof(DWORD));

        strcpy(msg + sizeof(DWORD), argv[1]);

        cout << strlen(msg) << endl;

        //
        WriteFile(pipe,
            msg,
            strlen(msg),
            &dwNumberOfBytesWritten,
            NULL);
```

Thank you

Comment: Calling `SetFilePointer` on a pipe handle isn't supported, as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer): *"Calling the `SetFilePointer` function with a handle to a non-seeking device such as a pipe or a communications device is not supported, even though the `SetFilePointer` function may not return an error."*

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix my issue?

Comment: `strlen(msg)` really ? it will be 1 or 2 bytes . `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` you understand what this is mean ? `SetNamedPipeHandleState` for what ? why you not call `GetLastError()` ?

Comment: @RbMm I see you are pointing at some issues in my code(feels more like that you hate my code!), can you please provide a solution as well?
Thanks

Comment: of course i can. in your code too many errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you not need call `SetNamedPipeHandleState` because pipe already in
  this state.
- you need check results of api call (like `ReadFile` )
- strlen(msg) is fatal error - in msg buffer not string but DWORD in
  first place. in your code here `strlen(argv[1])` so not more than
  `0x8000` bytes. as result `strlen(msg)` will be not more than 2
  bytes.
- in case `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` the `ReadFile` will return error
  `ERROR_MORE_DATA` if exist more bytes in message.
- too many extra variables and actions

demo minimal implementation:

```
#define pipename L"\\\\?\\pipe\\{664777DB-0CEB-466b-B346-6597DAE4F1C4}"

ULONG WINAPI Client(PVOID pcsz)
{
    HANDLE pipe = CreateFileW(pipename, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE|FILE_GENERIC_READ, 
        0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != pipe)
    {
        DWORD len = (DWORD)strlen((PCSTR)pcsz);

        PVOID msg = alloca(len + sizeof(DWORD));

        memcpy((char*)memcpy(msg, &len, sizeof(DWORD)) + sizeof(DWORD), pcsz, len);

        WriteFile(pipe,
            msg,
            len + sizeof(DWORD),
            &len,
            NULL);

        CloseHandle(pipe);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

int mm()
{
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(pipename,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, Client, const_cast<PSTR>("1234567890"), 0, 0))
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL))
    {
        DWORD IncomingBufferLength;
        DWORD dwNumRead;

        switch (ReadFile(hPipe,
            &IncomingBufferLength,
            sizeof(IncomingBufferLength),
            &dwNumRead, NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
        {
        case NOERROR:
            break;

        case ERROR_MORE_DATA:
            if (IncomingBufferLength - 1 < MAXUSHORT)
            {
                if (char* IncomingBuffer = new char[IncomingBufferLength])
                {
                    switch (ReadFile(hPipe,
                        IncomingBuffer,
                        IncomingBufferLength,
                        &IncomingBufferLength, NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())
                    {
                    case NOERROR:
                        DbgPrint("\"%.*s\"\n", IncomingBufferLength, IncomingBuffer);
                        break;
                    }

                    delete [] IncomingBuffer;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So i need to call `SetNamedPipeHandleState` on client code before calling WriteFile?
What im trying to write is to have echo client server that server reply back anything of any length that it received.

Comment: @David - are you see this call in my code ? i paste working code. and you really need message mode ?

Comment: Yes thanks for the effort, how can I turn this into echo service? How after the ReadFile I can have a WriteFile to return the same message and the ReadFile to read that over the pipe!
I keep getting error coded 109. Is there a quick way to turn your example to echo service over a named pipe?

Comment: @David this is already another question. you got `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` which is normal after client close self handle

Comment: Do you suggest that I ask another question to get help for my second problem?

Comment: I created another question asking about having echo service over named pipes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935387/cant-write-to-windows-named-pipe-after-read-operation-or-vice-versa

Comment: @David after you got `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`  you need call `DisconnectNamedPipe` and than `ConnectNamedPipe` if you want continue use it or `CloseHandle`